# Anconda env. python script autostart after reboot

Tags: anaconda, debian, environment, systemd

having a strange behaviour.

Setup:

- Debian 11 server on Proxmox
- added user mupsje (modded for sudo)
- installed anaconda3 on mupsje and root.
- created env discordbot.
- directory: /home/mupsje/discordbot/

sh. file: on_startup.sh (chmodded)

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/mupsje/anaconda3/envs/discordbot/bin/python /home/mupsje/discordbot/bot.py
```

above line bot.py

```
#!/home/mupsje/anaconda3/envs/discordbot/bin/python
import blablabla
```

Now I want to start this env and the shell script when the server is reboot.
When I login with credentials mupsje or root and test the shell script.

```
(base) mupsje@debian:$ cd /home/mupsje/discordbot/
(base) mupsje@debian:$ cd ~/discordbot$ ./on_startup.sh
```

Python scripts runs.

Now i'm trying to ad this in systemd as a service
discordbot.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Startup Discordbot

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/mupsje/discordbot/on_startup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

when I start and status the systemctl service.

```
sudo systemctl start discordbot.service
sudo systemctl status discordbot.service
```

I get a error back and the python is not running.

```
* discordbot.service - Startup Discordbot
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/discordbot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-09-05 13:05:18 UTC; 9s ago
    Process: 752 ExecStart=/home/mupsje/discordbot/on_startup.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 752 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 355ms

Sep 05 13:05:18 debian on_startup.sh[753]:     return future.result()
Sep 05 13:05:18 debian on_startup.sh[753]:   File "/home/mupsje/anaconda3/envs/discordbot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 817, in runner
Sep 05 13:05:18 debian on_startup.sh[753]:     await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
Sep 05 13:05:18 debian on_startup.sh[753]:   File "/home/mupsje/anaconda3/envs/discordbot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 745, in start
Sep 05 13:05:18 debian on_startup.sh[753]:     await self.login(token)
Sep 05 13:05:18 debian on_startup.sh[753]:   File "/home/mupsje/anaconda3/envs/discordbot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 577, in login
Sep 05 13:05:18 debian on_startup.sh[753]:     raise TypeError(f'expected token to be a str, received {token.__class__!r} instead')
Sep 05 13:05:18 debian on_startup.sh[753]: TypeError: expected token to be a str, received <class 'NoneType'> instead
Sep 05 13:05:18 debian systemd[1]: discordbot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 05 13:05:18 debian systemd[1]: discordbot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

regards
Mupsje

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself.

I used crontab for this, with webmin "execute cron job as"

```
@reboot /home/mupsje/discordbot/on_startup.sh
```

then in on_startup.sh file.

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate discordbot
echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
cd ~/discordbot/
python ppi_bot.py
conda deactivate
```

Works like a charm.
If you have better solutions, please let me know